# overflow-x: auto and line background color visibility on scroll

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS defined to have the horizontal scroll when I have overflow and at the same time, apply the background color for each line:

CSS:

```
ul.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.list li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
.content-holder {
      font-family: Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
  -ms-word-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <span class="content-holder">foo</span></li>
    <li>
        <span class="content-holder">foo foo foo foo foo foo</span></li>
    <li class="highlight">
        <span class="content-holder">bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I am not seeing background color for each line applied when I scroll to right:

[image]

What I am after is to apply the background color for the lines which has `.highlight` CSS class applied and the background needs to be for the the whole line (including the hidden part which gets visible during the scroll). At the same time, I don't want to apply the scroll bar to each line (like here: http://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/9/).

What am I missing here? Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/4/

Comment: why not just apply the background color to ul?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/3/

Comment: @AmmarCSE sorry, that was not my intention. Changed the question to reflect what I am really after.

Comment: do you need like this http://jsbin.com/tunisokuda/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2uny5eh/ . Is this what you need?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8jf8xsxr/

Comment: @KhanhTO nope: https://jsfiddle.net/8jf8xsxr/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0t9ppLcn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a bit, I finally figured out the correct answer. Big thanks to @mirek for [heading me to the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30459607/463785).

First of all, you need to set `ul` display as `table` and `li` display as `table-row`. Then, set both widths' to `100%`. Final touch is to wrap `ul` inside a `div` and give that div the scroll behavior. This works well for all the cases. Here is the update version of the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/22/

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
ul.list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-holder {
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: visible;
    -ms-word-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
        <li> <span class="content-holder">foo</span>
        </li>
        <li> <span class="content-holder">foo foo foo foo foo foo</span>
        </li>
        <li class="highlight"> <span class="content-holder">bar bar bar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar barbar bar bar bar bar bar</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add **display: table-row** to your css **ul.list li**

```
ul.list li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: table-row;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/13/

Comment: You're welcome ;) It highlights the whole width of row/line even if the text is shorter. Hope it's what you want to achieve
https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/19/

Comment: hmm, this turned out to be not the desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/sLbgmq8s/20/

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to change your LI elements to

```
display: inline-block;
```

[Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/or5dmxtw/)

Comment: do you think the problem is using the ul/li? I can get away with using tables if that's the case.

Comment: Well... What's the problem ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret the first line is highlighted for the length of text whereas it needs to go all the way to the end.

Comment: You get that with `overflow-x:auto` then. I guess I don't understand what's the  desired output :(

Comment: Updated the question to indicate my intend more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you're not targeting the span element containing text

```
.highlight > span{...}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/sLbgmq8s/12/)

Comment: the actual problem is that the `span` elements overflows the parent `li`element

Comment: you could probably get away using after pseudoelements (but I'll let you try that :)