# Select2 - Highlighted Option Background Colour Width When you have Long Strings?

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 to retrieve some remote data. The select2 dropdown is in fixed width div.

When I get the results and hover over a result option, the background is highlighted in blue and the font is white.

If I have result item with a very long string the highlighted background doesnt seem to highlight the full width of list item and  so you cant see text if the font colour is white.

How can I make the highlighted background of the list item span the full width of  the result.

```
<select id="example" style="width: 200px">
  <option></option>
  <option >Joe blogs (joe.blogs@gmail.com) </option>
  <option >AUserWithAVeryLongName AUserWithAVeryLongName (a.user.with.a.very.long.name@gmail.com)</option>
</select>

$('#example').select2({
   placeholder: 'Select'
});
```

See my pics to illustrate. In pic 1 I've changed the font to red so you can see what the selected item is.

[image]

In pic 2 the font is white and when you scroll horizontally to the end of the  result box you cannot see what the full text is.

[image]

Note in the example above only a single result item is returned and full string is

```
AUserWithAVeryLongName AUserWithAVeryLongName (a.user.with.a.very.long.name@gmail.com)
```

Comment: Could you provide the code please?

Comment: @Matt code provided

Comment: I am trying to use your code but I am not able to generate your issue above

Comment: @Matt I doubt you have understood the question. Use the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/rLmztr2d/ and replace all code with what I've posted on SO and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could solve your problem:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria selected] 
{ background-color: #5897fb;
  color: white;
  overflow-x:  inherit;
}
```

Comment: it seems to add an extra scrollbar under the first option when you hover over it?

Comment: @adam78 using the JSFiddle, and adding that style, I am not getting any extra scrollbar

Comment: hover over the first item in the list (joe blogs) and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I will try to provide a different solution asap

Comment: no it doesn't  because it reverts back to the original behaviour i.e. when you hover over the second item in the list the background doesn't fill the entire overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458958/overflow-x-auto-and-line-background-color-visibility-on-scroll)

```
.select2-container--bootstrap .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
    background-color: green;
    color: black;
    display: table-row;
}
```